# How to define own package name/bundle identifier when creating react native project

Tags: npm, react-native, react-native-ios, npx

Could give me somebody advice how to define own package name/bundle identifier when I creating new application in react native?

I used command **npx react-native MyApp --package=com.myCompany.myApp** or **npx react-native MyApp -package "com.myCompany.myApp"** but everytime npx created project with package name com.myApp instead of com.myCompany.myApp. I don't want to change package name manualy or help by react-native-rename because I want to set name in time of creation. So it is somehow posible?

Thanks so much guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. The `--package` switch [was removed](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12721) some time ago. But it's a pretty easy fix, as long as you do it right after creating your project (before running it for the first time). You'll need to use an editor that has a project-wide find and replace (Atom, VS Code, Nova, etc.).

First, initialize the project like so:

```
npx react-native init AwesomeProject
```

Then, do a project-wide find and replace:

```
com.awesomeproject → com.mycompany.myapp
```

As long as you do this *before* you run the app for the first time, there should only be a handful of replacements. If you want to be extra careful, you can make each change manually.

Then, just modify the folder structure to reflect the new package name:

```
src/main/java/com/awesomeproject → src/main/java/com/mycompany/myapp
```

If you needed to automate this for some reason, you would need to write your own script to make the above changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [react-native-rename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rename) to rename your application and define a Bundle Identifier:

```
npx react-native init AwesomeProject
cd AwesomeProject
npx react-native-rename "Awesome Project" -b br.com.joaops.AwesomeProject
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `--package-name` parameter:

```
npx react-native@latest init GlowCalculator --package-name com.codebusterspro.glowcalculator --title "Glow Calculator"
```

See https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/1111#issuecomment-1562278377

Comment: Thanks, this should be the accepted answer for 2024